# .htaccess redirect all URLs beginning with

Tags: .htaccess

I've already read all helps here and everywhere, but I can't solve my problem.
I got hundreds of urls [404 links](http://www.sistemacomo2015.it/rstu1s/it?LanguageISOCtxParam=it&sp=page4s&rstu1s.ctx4s.att1s=)
I would like use htaccess to redirect all URLS beginning with /rstu1s/it? and redirect to the root.
I did several attempts but I obtain always 404!!!

thanks
Tru

Comment: What did you try? Always paste your own code to get better help here and to show where you are going wrong

Comment: Something like RewriteRule ^rstu1s/it($) /index.php [R]
I know it doesn't works, I did several attempts. I would like that every link beginnig with a particular string, beeing redirect to the root.

Answer (score 5):

Using mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/rstu1s/it /
```

Using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^rstu1s/it / [L,R=301]
```

These all need to be in the htaccess file **in your document root**.